# Spring serving versioned static content on any version

Tags: spring-mvc

To serve static resources in Spring I can use the following code in my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resfolder/")
```

I can also use a fixed version number like

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources-5/**").addResourceLocations("/resfolder/")
```

and it will serve a url like "/resources-5/some.js".

What if I want to accept any version number? E.g. also "/resources-6/some.js" and "/resources-748573/some.js"

The following ant pattern doesn't work:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources-*/**").addResourceLocations("/resfolder/")
```

Also if I try by separating the version number with a slash, it doesn't work for a url like "/resources/5/some.js":

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/*/**").addResourceLocations("/resfolder/")
```

Comment: Why do you think that `/resources-*/**` does not work?

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't work